# React: Overwrite an array with another array. Error: Uncaught TypeError: ...is not a function

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am currently working on a todo app in React. In the function handleClearTodos I would like to delete all todos with the status: Done. To do this, I run through the array todos in this function and write all todos with the status: Open into a new array with the name cleanedTodos. At the end, when I want to overwrite the content of todos with the content of cleanedTodos, I get the following error message:

Uncaught TypeError: currentTodos.forEach is not a function

This is a function in the Todo component which separates the todos with the status: Open from those with the status: Done, stores them in two different arrays and renders them separately in the render function.

TodoTable.js (Parent Component)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { InputBar } from "./InputBar";
import { Todo } from "./Todo";


let currentTodos = [];

export const TodoTable = ({ mockTodos }) => {

    //Konstruktor
    if(mockTodos){
        currentTodos = mockTodos;
    }
   
    
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(currentTodos);
    const [enterTodo, setEnterTodo] = useState('');


    //Enter Todo handler
    const handleEnterTodo = (event) => {
      setEnterTodo(event.target.value);
    };
  

    //Clear Todo handler
    const handleClearTodos = (event) => {
        let cleanedTodos = []

        todos.forEach((element, index) => {
            if(todos[index].status != 'open'){
                //console.log(todos[index])
                cleanedTodos.push(todos[index]);

 
            }
        });

        setTodos({ todos: cleanedTodos });
        
        console.log(typeof cleanedTodos);
        console.log(todos);
    }
    

    //Create Todo handler
    const handleCreateTodo = (event) => {

        //create new Todo
        const newTodo = {
            id: todos.length,
            describtion: enterTodo,
            status: 'open'
        };

        
        setTodos(todos => 
            [
                newTodo,
                ...todos
        
            ]
        );
    };
  
  

    return(
            <>
                <InputBar 
                    enterTodo={ enterTodo } 
                    handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo } 
                    handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
                    handleClearTodos= { handleClearTodos }
                />
                <Todo currentTodos={ todos } />
            </>      
    );
}
```

Todo.js (Child Component)

```
import React from "react";

export const Todo = ({ currentTodos }) => {
    
    
    let openTodo = [];
    let doneTodo = [];
    // just for develope
    const lineBreak = <hr></hr>
    
    currentTodos.forEach((element, index) => {
        if(currentTodos[index].status == 'open'){
            
            let todoOpen = (
                
                <div className="openTodos" key={ currentTodos[index].id.toString() }>
                    {currentTodos[index].describtion}
                    {/*Buttons*/}
                    {/*Buttons*/}
                </div>
            );
            openTodo = 
            [
                ...openTodo,
                todoOpen
            ]
        }
        else{
            
            let todoDone = (
                
                <div className="doneTodos" key={ currentTodos[index].id.toString() }>
                    {currentTodos[index].describtion}
                    {/*Buttons*/}
                    {/*Buttons*/}
                </div>
            );
            doneTodo = 
            [
                ...doneTodo,
                todoDone
            ]
        }
        
      })
    
    return(
        <>
            {openTodo}
            {lineBreak}
            {doneTodo}
        </>
    );
}
```

InputBar (Child Component)

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "./components/Button";

export const InputBar = ({ enterTodo, handleEnterTodo, handleCreateTodo, handleClearTodos}) => {
  console.log(enterTodo);
    return(
        <>
      <form>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={enterTodo}
          onChange={handleEnterTodo}
        />
        <Button lable= 'ADD'  disabled= { enterTodo == '' } onClick= { handleCreateTodo } />
        <Button lable= 'CLEAR' onClick= { handleClearTodos } />

      </form>
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function ***forEach*** can be used for variables which are type ***Array***. Your prop ***currentTodos*** is not an array, you set this to object:

```
setTodos({ todos: cleanedTodos });
```

This code return your todos:

```
console.log(todos.todos) // returning your cleanedTodos array
```

But in your parent component you init state as array, so it always should be array